# WebAssembly: Duplicating the top of stack

Tags: bytecode, webassembly

There is not `dup` instruction, one that lets me duplicate the top of the stack. Which instruction sequence can I use to replicate this behavior?

Comment: Can you please give a bit more context? Why are you wanting to duplicate stack values? Typically linear memory is used for program / working memory rather than the stack

Comment: The necessity of using a computed value twice or more appears very often. My intuition is that using memory is much slower and too complicated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wasm doesn't have stack juggling primitives because it has locals. To duplicate the top of the operand stack you need to define a local variable of the right type. Then you can e.g. use the following instruction sequence:

```
(tee_local $x) (get_local $x)
```

where `$x` is your variable.